# Is it normal that my laptop CPU is that busy that it shows shows 90% to 100% utilization?

Tags: cpu, windows-11

Every time I play any game even if I’m on my browser my CPU shows 90% to 100% utilization and I’m not that sure if it’s normal.

This is an image of Windows Task Manager when I am playing a game:

[image: this is the picture from my Task Manager when I play a game]

Comment: Yes, it is normal.  If you don't really have a problem, I wouldn't create one.  Wouldn't you PREFER that your computer was going as fast as it can?  Also, taskmanager is adding cycles to your CPU.

Comment: If you are playing a game, then yes… That CPU usage is normal.

Comment: just be sure to check the frequency as well. if you are using 100% but your CPU frequency is being throttled due to thermal or power considerations, then you have a problem to fix. a CPU with proper cooling and power, running at 100% should always be at full frequency.

Comment: Depending on the game and CPU then yes it could well be normal. We have no idea about either of those two things though as there are no details in your question.

Comment: your CPU usage in your image is 73% - far from "90-100%" - so, why do you believe your CPU is at 90 to 100?

Answer (score 1):

There really is no such thing as "normal."  Everyone has different computer hardware, software, and settings that will result in a different "normal" for them.

Depending on the game you are playing and the settings you are running a (resolution, antialiasing level, etc) the GPU can be working really hard.  There is nothing wrong with the GPU being in the 90% range or even 100%.  If its constantly at 100%, then the GPU might not be able to reliably play the game at the setting you have chosen.  If the game is performing poorly, you might want to turn down the settings.  Some games can autdetect the "best" settings.  I see you have an nVidia card.  nVidia's GeForce Experience software can scan your computer for games and detect the "best" settings as well.